# Primefaces ManyCheckbox to array

Tags: java, arrays, jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I got the following problem.
I got a datatable in a datatable
Example:

```
<p:dataTable var="mainarea">
  ...
  <p:dataTable value="#{bean.subarea(mainarea)" selection="#{bean.selectedsubarea}">
    <p:colum selectionMode="multiple"/>
     ...
  </p:dataTable>
</p:dataTable>
```

It works fine as long as the first table only generates 1 result.

[image]

But as soon as there are 2 tables ill get a NullPointerException.

[image]

The problem should be that I need to write into #{bean.selectedsubarea[x]} so every subarea list got his own array but I dont know how to realise that.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am clearly able to understand your question you can use [Primefaces Sub Table](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf)

with [Expandable Datatble](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf)

may be it will you

Comment: Well the problem is not the datatable, the problem is caused by the manycheckbox ( <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/> ) and saving it into an array.

Comment: Can it possible for you to provide any demo code so i can replicate the issue?

Comment: Sure, sadly I cant post anything here because I got to less reputation. So here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/KGMj0W58

Comment: Thanks But i will want simple demo code with some Dummy data i will not get much time to change in your code can you please paste code with some Dummydata from java bean?

Comment: I hope this helps you out, dont know what exactly you need! http://pastebin.com/a15gjFhz

Comment: Sample data would look like this: mainAreaList{object a, object b} and every object of subArea got a id of his mainArea in it. So in the table the expendable row of the mainAreaTable will display a table with his subAreas. Those should be selectable with a checkbox.

Comment: Okay I fixed it with some easy listeners.